# Xquery while using distinct-values

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

XML File

```
<map>

    <links>
        <link id="10" ordernum="0"></link>
        <link id="20" ordernum="1"></link>
        <link id="30" ordernum="2"></link>
    </links>

    <products>
        <product id="10" group="2">...</product>
        <product id="20" group="1">...</product>
        <product id="30" group="2">...</product>
    </products>

</map>
```

I'm using the following Xquery to get the `products/@id`, ordered by the corresponding `link/@ordernum` but only once for the same group.

```
for $linkid in //links/link
order by $linkid/@ordernum
return distinct-values(data(//products/product[@id=data($linkid/@id)]/@id))
```

Expected output:
10, 20

Received output:
10, 20, 30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's returning all products because all product id's match a link id. (This part of your return statement: `product[@id=data($linkid/@id)]`)

Maybe try doing the `for` loop over the product groups first...

```
for $prodgroup in distinct-values(/map/products/product/@group)
let $prodid := /map/products/(product[@group=$prodgroup])[1]/@id
order by /map/links/link[@id = $prodid]/@ordernum
return data(/map/products/product[@id=$prodid]/@id)
```

Comment: How to modify this part to get all data from the products? If i change the last line to: `return /map/products/product[@id=$prodid]` it only returns one product

Comment: if i do `return data ($prodid)`it returns me the correct multiple ids

Comment: @frgtv10 - What processor are you using? I'm using Saxon-HE 9.5 and changing the last line to `return /map/products/product[@id=$prodid]` correctly returns both `product` elements.